# How do you do Create Class of Assembly using Reflection in .Net Standard 2.1

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-standard

How do you do this in .Net Standard 2.1

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance("SomeAssemblyName", "SomeClass");
instance.Unwrap()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to create the assemblies in .netCore using the below code,

```cs
var myAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"Directory_Path");
var myType = myAssembly.GetType("Class_Name");
var myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

In .Net Standard also, it should work.

**Edit:**
Try this for .NetStandard,

```cs
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("directoryPath");
var type = assembly.GetType("ClassName");

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: I am getting this error when i run the application "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Is the System.Runtime.Loader assembly referred in your application? If yes, please check if multiple versions are installed in different projects and correct them

Comment: The problem is with this line "var myAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyName(assemblyNameObject);"

Comment: How do I check all the projects which have the System.Runtime.Loader and how do i check their versions. In my .Net Standard projects I have used Nuget. and also in my 4.7.2 Forms project, I have used Nuget and added System.Runtime.Loader. But they all have the Same latest version. In the Object Browser it is showing a single entry of System.Runtime.Loader

Comment: Run this,

"%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.Loader"

This should let you know the locally installed versions

Comment: It will show whatever installed in your system. If you want to check in your solution, you need to use the solution explorer in VS and search it

Comment: When we nuget a package in a winform application, you cannot see it in the references and nothing like a packages folder is created. So basically where does it get installed, because it cannot be seen. Does it mean it did not get installed in the project. It did not give errors as such.

Comment: I Checked there is only 1 version installed in the system and in solution, System.Runtime.Loader version 4.3.0...But I just checked in nuget, and .Net Standard 2.0 and .Net Framework 4.7.2 is not mentioned in Nuget description of System.Runtime.Loader version 4.3.0

Comment: That's true, looks like System.Runtime.Loader is supported only in .netcore.
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22142

Comment: Edited the answer for .Net Standard.

Comment: If you still face any issue, Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203003/discussion-between-badri-and-beegees).

Comment: Thanx a ton badri. But i just did a workaround by passing the Assembly object itself to the .Net standard library project. There is one more question i have posted which is for How to use C# code to list all Namespaces in the .Net Standard library from within the .Net standard project itself. Can you see that. It is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59026604/how-to-use-c-sharp-code-to-list-all-namespaces-in-netstandard-library-in-a-net