# How to use C# Code to List all Namespaces in .NetStandard Library in a .Net Standard Project

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, .net-standard-2.0

How to use C# Code to List all Namespaces in .NetStandard Library 2.0 from within a .Net Standard Project.

This is the Code which gives Namspaces in netStandard Library is 0;

```
            foreach (AssemblyName fooAssemblyName in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(fooAssemblyName.FullName);
                var namespaces = assembly.GetTypes()
                    .Select(t => t.Namespace).Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
                    .Distinct();
                int count = namespaces.Count();
                if (fooAssemblyName.Name == "netstandard")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(count); // THIS GIVES 0 for .Net Standard Library
                }
            }
```

Comment: "...does not seem to work..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Comment: Can't reproduce this problem. I guess you referenced the library but didn't actually use any class.

Comment: As i mentioned in the code, the Count() is 0. Which means there are No Namespaces for the. Net standard

Comment: I have updated the Code. please see now.

Comment: I am looking to get a list of all the namespaces in the netStandrad library.

Comment: works fine here; if I replace the `if (...)` etc with just `Console.WriteLine($"{fooAssemblyName.Name}: {count}");` (so it lists all of them), I get `System.Runtime: 9`, `System.Linq: 4`, `System.Console: 4`. Are you sure that you have a library with the correct name, that you reference it, and that it actually has types in it?